# Turn of timer while video is playing?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, timer, media

Is there anyway you can pause the timer if a movie is played? The reason why I'm asking is because I'm using a `MediaElement` that uses both images and videos and therefore I have to find a solution to turn of the timer while the movie is played.

Something like this:

If movie is playing

`DispatcherTimer.Stop`

...

Else if movie is not playing

`DispatcherTimer.Start`

Something like that?

I already have a code that checks if the files is images or videos. All I need is help to turn of timer while movie is playing.

I'm using the timer to change picture every 20 seconds.

Comment: There are `Stop` and `Start` methods. Have you actually tried calling them? Or do you not know how to tell if the movie is playing?

Comment: @JimMischel
That I already know.
But I want to call the timer when the movie is ended too.
Like in the example...

Comment: So what's the problem? Have you actually tried doing this? If not, why? You haven't yet asked a question that we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set LoadedBehaviour and UnloadedBehaviour properties of the MediaElement to manual. Then you will be able to control the start, pause and stop of the video. Once, you do that, all it remains is to start the timer whenever you stop/pause the video, and vice-versa. Something like this:

```
    //myvideo is a <MediaElement/>
    private void cmdStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myvideo.Play();
        DispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void cmdStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myvideo.Stop();
        DispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    private void cmdPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myvideo.Pause();
        DispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
```